# Creating queue in share memory POSIX

Tags: c, posix, mmap

For my implementation I am using `mmap` for allocating shared memory for interprocess communication. In this shared memory I initialize a queue (I set first and last pointer to NULL).

The problem is how to push new item into the Queue. Normally I would use a `malloc` to allocate my 'queue item struct' and then point to it, but I can't use that, can I? I need to allocate it somehow in the shared memory. I probably could use another `mmap` and push the item there and then point to it, but it doesn't seem right, because I would have to do that multiple times.

Can this be done simply or I should think about different solutions?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General rules to create a queue in shared memory:

1) Never use pointers as shared elements, because the OS may choose different virtual addresses in different processes. Always use offsets from the shared memory view base address, or array indices, or anyway something that is position-independent.

2) You have to manually partition your shared memory. E.g. you must know how many items your queue may contain, and dimension the shared area so it can contain the "haeder" (insertion index and extraction index...) and the item array. It's often enough to define a structure that contains both the "header" and the "item array" of the correct size: the memory size is sizeof(your_structure), its address is the one returned by mmap.

3) Carefully consider multithreading and multiprocessing issues. Protect the access to the shared memory with a mutex if it's acceptable that the accessing threads may block. But if you want to create a "non-blocking" queue, you must at least use atomic operations to change the relevant fields, and consider any possible timing issue.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your advices, it's much appreciated. Using an array instead of linked list sounds much more easier. The only downside I can see is, that using an array I will occupy more space that I actually need at the moment. That was the reason I decided for linked list in the first place, but I didn't realize the clause 1) in your answer. thx again